# ProGuard doesn't obfuscate JAR with dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, proguard, obfuscation

I have a project with the `pom.xml` file given below. When I issue the command `mvn clean compile assembly:single install` I want Maven to generate a JAR, which contains

- all the dependencies and
- obfuscated version of my code.

It doesn't work - my code is not obfuscated in the "jar-with-dependencies" file.

When I run `mvn clean compile install` the resulting file contains obfuscated code of my application, but no dependencies.

What can I do in order to have a JAR file with all the dependencies and my obfuscated code?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproduct</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <restlet-version>2.3.5</restlet-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spongepowered</groupId>
            <artifactId>spongeapi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0M8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>templating-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>filter-src</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>filter-sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>proguard</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <proguardVersion>5.2</proguardVersion>
                    <options>
                        <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                        <option>-dontoptimize</option>
                        <option>-dontshrink</option>
                        <option>-dontnote</option>
                        <option>-keepattributes Signature</option>
                        <option>-keep class com.mycompany.MyPlugin { *; }</option>
                    </options>
                    <libs>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                    </libs>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                            <version>5.2</version>
                            <scope>runtime</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Update 1 (17.01.2016 19:54 MSK):** Changed the ProGuard configuration like shown below, but `mvn clean compile assembly:single` still produces a JAR with unobfuscated class files.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>proguard</goal></goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <proguardVersion>5.2</proguardVersion>
        <options>
            <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
            <option>-dontoptimize</option>
            <option>-dontshrink</option>
            <option>-dontnote</option>
            <option>-keepattributes Signature</option>
            <option>-keep class com.mycompany.MyPlugin { *; }</option>
        </options>
        <injar>${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</injar>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
        </libs>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                <version>5.2</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Update 2 (17.01.2016 20:29 MSK):** `mvn clean compile assembly:single install` fails. The last messages can be seen [here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s35/sh/278de801-ac5c-41d5-bd12-55e4c006b1af/0cc6004df2b49c34ff6198e4a7e52875).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`proguard-maven-plugin` will obfuscate the primary artifact of your project, not the secondary artifact `jar-with-dependencies` that the `maven-assembly-plugin` generated.

You need to configure the plugin to obfuscate the `jar-with-dependencies` by specifying the [`injar`](http://pyx4me.com/pyx4me-maven-plugins/proguard-maven-plugin/proguard-mojo.html#injar) attribute:

> Specifies the input jar name (or wars, ears, zips) of the application to be processed.

```xml
<injar>${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</injar>
```

Now, there is also a problem in the order of execution of plugins in your POM: we need to make sure that the `maven-assembly-plugin` is executed before the `proguard-maven-plugin`. As such, it is best to define an explicit execution for the `maven-assembly-plugin` bound to the `package` phase instead of manually invoking it from the command line with `assembly:single`. This would be the configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>assembly</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and then, you just need to make sure that the `proguard-maven-plugin` plugin configuration is after that in your POM.

Having done that, invoking Maven with `mvn clean install` will result in an obfuscated jar with dependencies.

---

To test with your actual POM, I added two repositories:

- `https://repo.spongepowered.org/maven` to resolve the `spongeapi` dependency.
- `http://maven.restlet.com` to resolve the `org.restlet.jse` dependencies.

With those 2 dependencies, warnings were generated by ProGuard because the `org.restlet.ext.jackson` dependency utilizes `com.sun.msv.*` classes that are not on the buildpath. Since I figure that your code is currently working, it means those classes don't need to be included and that those warnings can be ignored. As such, I added the `-dontwarn` option so that ProGuard doesn't error when there is a warning.

The final POM for which I was able to successfully obfuscate the jar with dependencies is the following:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproduct</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>spongepowered</id>
           <url>https://repo.spongepowered.org/maven</url>
       </repository>
       <repository>
           <id>restlet</id>
           <url>http://maven.restlet.com</url>
       </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <restlet-version>2.3.5</restlet-version>
    </properties>
    <build>
       <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>templating-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>filter-src</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>filter-sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assembly</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>proguard</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <injar>${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</injar> <!-- make sure to obfuscate the jar with dependencies -->
                            <proguardVersion>5.2</proguardVersion>
                            <options>
                                <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                                <option>-dontoptimize</option>
                                <option>-dontshrink</option>
                                <option>-dontnote</option>
                                <option>-dontwarn</option> <!-- added option to ignore com.sun missing classes -->
                                <option>-keepattributes Signature</option>
                                <option>-keep class com.mycompany.MyPlugin { *; }</option>
                            </options>
                            <libs>
                                <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                            </libs>
                            <dependencies>
                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                                    <version>5.2</version>
                                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                                </dependency>
                            </dependencies>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spongepowered</groupId>
            <artifactId>spongeapi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0M8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I'm stuck with the same issue and I don't get your answer. Why do you need to add the repositories ? The dependencies are already specified in the pom. Why does Proguard needs more ? Moreover, where do you find the repository for each dependency ? Would you mind having a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150297/how-to-assembly-a-project-after-using-proguard-maven-plugin?noredirect=1#comment59941093_36150297

Comment: @tunaki , Im getting this error,
Cleaning up unclosed ZipFile for archive /Users/sulhadin/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar
[INFO] Total time:  03:10 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-05T09:56:40+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] GC overhead limit exceeded -> [Help 1]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: @sulhadin The error indicated that your zip file was so large that it ran out of memory when using the default allocation size. As a result, you will need to run Maven with more memory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498738/maven-out-of-memory-build-failure for information on how to tell Maven to tell the JVM to allocate more heap space using the MAVEN_OPTS variable.

Comment: In my case, adding `-dontwarn` passed building, but the output file `*-jar-with-dependencies.jar` is not obfuscated/optimized, I still can see all classes inside it.