# How to package a jar and all dependencies within a new jar with maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a maven project with like ten dependencies. Before, I used to pack all of that in a single jar thanks to `maven-assembly-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-executable-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>myApp.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But now, I added a step before. I have a plugin that will generate the jar of my application. So I just want the assembly plugin to add the dependencies to this jar. Unfortunately, the plugin doesn't use this jar, but instead, seems tu be using the result from the compiler.

is there a way to specify that I want the plugin to use the previously generated jar instead of the result from the compiler ?

Comment: What do you mean *add the dependencies to this jar*? Who generates the JAR? This is not as simple as that. You need to have a proper Manifest.

Comment: Basically, it is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150297/how-to-assembly-a-project-after-using-proguard-maven-plugin?noredirect=1#comment59948505_36150297 but with another approach. Proguard successfully generate an obfuscated jar, but I can't figure out how to add the dependencies afterwards. I could also add the dependencies and then obfuscate, but Proguard fails in this case (unresolved references...)

Comment: That's not how you want to do that. Definitely not. Solve the problem in that other question, you're hurting yourself here.

Comment: Hum, ok, but, first, why not ? Then, how ? As I said, I can't apply proguard on the packed jar with dependencies because then Proguard fail to find the references to libraries... And I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the maven-shade-plugin. You need something like:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: OMG ! It worked ! 3 days I'm fighting with this, I was becoming mad. I want to hug you man !

Comment: just glad to help - no hug is required  ;^)