# Maven add dependencies to project

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

In eclipse you can easily add dependencies (i.e. a JAR file) to you're project.
Right click on the project and click -> Build Path-> add libraries.

Now a hidden file is createn inside the project, ".classpath".
Inside this file is a classpathEntry added so now I can use the libraries by adding it in a java file:

```
import foo.bar.*;
```

This "application" can now be exported to a single jar.

How can I achieve this with Maven and without eclipse?
I switched to emacs... :)

With the command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-cli -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I get myself a sample start application.
inside a src folder is a App.java file writing "hello World" on a commandline.

with the following in the pom.xml I obtain myself a jar inside my project(maven indedependent deployment) successfully:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
                     <groupId>com.mycompany.third-party</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-cli-archetype</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <type>jar</type>
         <overWrite>false</overWrite>
         <!--${project.basedir}     ${project.build.directory} -->
         <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/resources/repo</outputDirectory>
         <destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/resources/repo</outputDirectory>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Now how can I use this jar inside my App.java?
Do I have to create a .classpath file manually?
How can I arrange my classpathentries automatically?
I have been trying to create a manifest.MF with the classpassentries but with no success. I have tried several tutorials.

I had no success with:

```
     <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
    <include>${project.basedir}
    /resources/repo/optional-          new-name.jar</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

 <plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true
   </addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <mainClass>your.main.Class</mainClass>



        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
          <Class-Path>${project.basedir}/resources/repo</Class-Path>

        </manifestEntries>

     <manifestFile>
    <!--
       ${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

    -->
     ${project.basedir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
         </manifestFile>

    </archive>

<!--
  <archive>
    <manifest>
      <mainClass>com.mkyong.core.App</mainClass>
    </manifest>
    </archive>
    -->


</configuration>
```

after creating the manifest.MF manually.

after the command

```
mvn clean install
```

the manifest.MF remains empty.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve? What kind of jar do you want to build? Why do you want to have a "jar inside the project"?

Comment: Yes. Inside the app.java file I would like to import my jar. And use it's classes. Just as you would using eclips and add a library to you're project.

Comment: With Maven you install your jars into the local repository or deploy them to a Nexus/Artifactory. Then you reference them as <dependency> in the pom file. Is there a reason you don't want to do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for not using eclipse  ;^)

If you are looking to reference code from another JAR then try adding the following to your POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
        <version>zzz</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Where xxx, yyy and zzz are the maven coordinates for the JAR you want to import. You can get these from your Nexus

**Edit:**

So for example if you were looking to import Joda time it would be

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you are looking to combine the contents of all your dependencies with your code and release them as a single JAR then you might want to take a look at the maven-shade-plugin. See [How to package a jar and all dependencies within a new jar with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158965/how-to-package-a-jar-and-all-dependencies-within-a-new-jar-with-maven/36159586#36159586)

And one other thing, you should never play with the .classpath file. This is something Eclipse specific. Changing it won't effect Maven and will probably confuse Eclipse

Comment: Thank you for you're answer. I have been maven strugling for days.

Comment: What instead of the .classpath can I use.

Comment: I have been trying: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-create-a-fat-jar-file-one-jar-example/ . I have no code completion with my emacs . So with this example I was glad that I got to know how to use the imports in the App.java file. But however with the eclipse .classpath. How can I use the imports without it? I also had the error:"org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin:1.4.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:". Anyone? Is there an easy non-eclipse way to do this?

Comment: Is this it?      <dependency>
   <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
   <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
   <version>${jodatime.version}</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Now I can just imort classes from joda-time?

Comment: .classpath is only read by Eclipse. If you are not using Eclipse you don't need to bother about it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
I followed this tutorial until step 5.
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-create-a-fat-jar-file-one-jar-example/

Instead of doing step 5 I added:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

To the pom.
and voila:

```
  mvn package
```

and

```
   java -jar target/dateutils.jar
```

Now it works.

So thanks for you're help Stormcloud!
So what happened? Still no resources spotted in my .jar.
The jar got shaded. 
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
What if I want to export my jar on a server without maven. So how to export a complete working jar?

Thanks again!

Comment: The resources where in the jar! I had so many tries. I looked in the wrong folder. :D

Comment: You can find a working XML description for the shade plugin in the link I previously added