# How do I obfuscate a WAR project which contains multiple other JARs using maven?

Tags: java, maven, proguard

I'm trying to find a way to obfuscate a **WAR** packaged project that is built with maven using Proguard (open to other tools).

I have /WEB-INF/lib/ directory that contains all the jars that the application depends on and the webapp under /WEB-INF/classes/

I tried passing the WAR file directly to proguard but was told it won't work, that I need to work with jars (I was getting 50k warnings).

I passed the webapp jar to proguard and it works, however, I need all the related dependencies to be obfuscated as well and here I don't know how to keep going.

Shall I copy all dependencies into a folder along with the webapp jar, obfuscate them and then insert them into the war? Somehow I feel maven is not the right tool for this kind of job.
Basically I need a step in between jar and war packaging that produces an obfuscated output of all the jars.

Asking to whoever had the <strike>curse</strike> task of doing something similar.

Comment: Why do you need this level of obfuscation?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706466/how-do-i-use-proguard-obfuscation-while-building-a-maven-plugin-package

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen App will be deployed on client server, and we don't want to make it so easy for them to just read our code. I know that with effort it can be reverse engineered but we want to make it hard.

Comment: @Johnson Note that you need to be able to read stack traces coming back through logfiles and bugreports, hence extra bookkeeping.   Also, the "do not read our code" is normally enforced through legally binding contracts as suitably motivated programmers can read anything a computer can run.  Why the distrust of your client?

Comment: Technically there is byte code under the hood which means that can be read.. maybe names are not that readable.. etc. but that not really prevent someone of decompiling the code...

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use a third party tool like **Proguard**

- first you will need to add proguard to your pom.xml

```
   

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.14</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Proguard configuration options go here -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

- create configuration file for proguard in the root of your project proguard.conf

  ```
      -dontshrink
  -dontoptimize
  -keep class your.package.name.** { *; }
  ```
- Configure Maven to use proguard

  ```
      <configuration>
      <proguardInclude>${basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
  </configuration>
  ```
- build and run